# Why does this limit exist?$\lim_{x\to1-n}\Gamma(x)(x+n-1)^n$

Tags: limits

I'm curious why $\lim_{x\to1-n}\Gamma(x)(x+n-1)^n$ exists for positive integers $n$ and in most cases is $0$

Comment: probably is related to this inequality $$\Gamma(x)(x+n-1)^\underline n=\Gamma(x+n)\le \Gamma(x)(x+n-1)^n$$ for some kind of $x$, in particular for $x>0$.

Comment: I *love* how I can't read Mathjax on mobile...

Comment: Hint: Render MathJax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\Gamma(x + 1) = x \Gamma(x)$ wherever the gamma-function is defined, we have
$$ \Gamma(x) = \frac{\Gamma(x + n)}{x(x+1)\dots(x+n-1)}$$
So
\begin{multline} \lim_{x \to 1- n}\Gamma(x) (x + n-1)^n = \Gamma(1) \times \lim_{x \to 1 - n} \frac{(x + n - 1)^n}{x(x+1)\dots(x+ n - 1)} \\ =  \lim_{x \to 1 - n} \frac{(x + n - 1)^{n-1}}{x(x+1)\dots(x+ n - 2)} = \frac{0^{n-1}}{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!} = 0.\end{multline}

By the same method, we can derive the stronger result that
$$ \lim_{x \to 1 - n} \Gamma(x)(x + n-1)^2 = 0$$
(In complex analysis, we say that $\Gamma(x)$ has a simple pole at $x = 1-n$ when  $n$ is a positive integer.)